# google amp carousel doest not autoplay using nextjs

Tags: amp-html

I have 3 content inside the carousel but setting the property autoplay isn't working for all browsers. I'm wondering if there's something specific I have to do for next.js?

I have 3 content inside the carousel but setting the property autoplay isn't working for all browsers. I'm wondering if there's something specific I have to do for next.js?

```
<amp-carousel
            height="400"
            width="400"
            type="slides"
            autoplay="autoplay"
            delay="2000"
            loop="loop"
          >
            <div class="testimonials-card">
              <amp-fit-text
                width="300"
                height="250"
                layout="fixed"
                max-font-size="25"
              >
                Share what your customers are saying about your products, your
                company...
              </amp-fit-text>
              <amp-img
                src="frederick_mfinanga_avatar.jpg"
                width="80"
                height="80"
              ></amp-img>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials-card">
              <amp-fit-text
                width="300"
                height="250"
                layout="fixed"
                max-font-size="25"
              >
                I've worked with Fred a few times, he's a creative and fun
                person to work with
              </amp-fit-text>
              <amp-img
                src="frederick_mfinanga_avatar.jpg"
                width="80"
                height="80"
              ></amp-img>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials-card">
              <amp-fit-text
                width="300"
                height="250"
                layout="fixed"
                max-font-size="25"
              >
                Share what your customers are saying about your products, your
                company...
              </amp-fit-text>
              <amp-img
                src="frederick_mfinanga_avatar.jpg"
                width="80"
                height="80"
              ></amp-img>
            </div>
          </amp-carousel>
```

am using `export const config = { amp: true };` to set up the amp page on nextjs

Comment: per similar question about `amp-image-lightbox`, what happens when you change `autoplay="autoplay"` to `autoplay`?

Comment: i get a validation error, i think its how nextjs is setup `error  The attribute 'autoplay' in tag 'AMP-CAROUSEL' is set to the invalid value 'true'.  https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-carousel`
the component still renders but doesn't autoplay

Comment: we don't use a generator, so i'm uncertain what is "getting in the way". i can tell you that we do not assign any values to `lightbox` or `autoplay` and our instances are valid and work as expected. recommendation: over-ride (edit) the generated code with working solutions.

Comment: That's what is printed on the console even though the code works, as in renders but doesn't autoplay. Same thing if i delete all my code and copy paste a code block from the documentation.
When i try to add the script for the carousel from the documentation to my header, the carousel doesn't show, but nextjs adds it when you use the components, so i shouldn't need to, just not sure if its a version issue or not

Comment: I think you know the answer here; nextjs is hurting you not helping you. Find the source of pain and replace it with a pain-free solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<amp-carousel height="400" width="400" type="slides" controls="" loop="" autoplay="" delay="2000">...</amp-carousel>
```

Just tested and it's working without any amp errors

Comment: Man you're a lifesaver! Setting autoplay="" did the trick for me. Thanks a lot.